# Calling a function in a function. Error says that it is not a function

Tags: typescript

This is the error I get when I run the code:

> TypeError: this.NewSprite is not a function

The function is clearly there, but gives that error regardless. This is the problematic call to the function

```
        OnJSONLoad(response) {
        //store JSONarray in variable
        this.json = JSON.parse(response);
        srcArray = this.json;
        this.atlasImage = new Image();
        this.atlasImage.src = 'Assets/' + srcArray.meta.image;
        image.src = 'Assets/' + srcArray.meta.image;
        var holder = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < srcArray.frames.length; i++) {
            holder[i] = this.NewSprite(srcArray.frames[i].filename);//this is the call!
        }
        AtlasCache[AtlasKey[atlasPos]] = holder;
        atlasPos++;
        OnComplete();
    }
}
```

This is the NewSprite function declared right before the `OnJSONLoad():`

```
NewSprite(spriteName) {
        this.isFound = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < srcArray.frames.length; i++) {
            //search for array element to matches the filename of the frame
            if (srcArray.frames[i].filename == spriteName) {
                var spriteWanted = srcArray.frames[i];
                this.isFound = true;
                //return new sprite function with all the dimensions and data of the frame
                return new this.defineSprite(this.atlasImage, spriteWanted.frame.x, spriteWanted.frame.y, spriteWanted.frame.w, spriteWanted.frame.h);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!this.isFound) {
            alert("Error: Sprite \"" + spriteName + "\" not found");
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will probably find that the "this" value is not the object you're expecting, especially if it's being called from a AJAX onSuccess.  Try using an Arrow function to declare your OnJSONLoad function to encapsulate the class instance.  If you need more assistance you will need to post the entire class so we can get some more context

Comment: Wow it worked although it seems a little messy. Thank you though, been agonizing over this for hours!

Answer (score 0):

By using an arrow function as Robert Slaney suggested, it worked!

```
           var OnJSONLoad = (response) => {
            this.json = JSON.parse(response);
            srcArray = this.json;
            this.atlasImage = new Image();
            this.atlasImage.src = 'Assets/' + srcArray.meta.image;
            image.src = 'Assets/' + srcArray.meta.image;
            var holder = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < srcArray.frames.length; i++) {
                holder[i] = this.NewSprite(srcArray.frames[i].filename);
            }
```

Comment: If you look at the generated javascript you will see that "this" is captured as a variable in the constructor as "_this", and the typescript compiler rewrites the OnJSONLoad function to use "_this" in place of "this".